# How to properly parse C# List of objects to Javascript. Only shows type like " System.Collections.Generic.List`1"

Tags: javascript, c#, json, parsing, kendo-ui

I really cant wrap my head around this i have a List of this class

```
public class StandardText
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

I then want to use it in javascript where i pass down a model to a partialView. The problem is that i dont seem to be able to use it. i tried to JSON.parse() the list in the javascript but it will then try to JSON.parse() something like " System.Collections.Generic.List`1" so it is not trying to actually parse the values of the object. i also tried to JsonConvert before i send it down but i am failing on how to porperly convert it.

this is where i create the model and then send down the partialView

```
public async Task<ActionResult> _confirmText(TextViewModel model)
    {
        model.StandardText = await GetStandardText();
        return PartialView(model);
    }
```

Then in that partialView i simply want to pass it to my frontend via a global scope(i know bad)

```
var text = '@Model.StandardText';
window.addElementToModal(element, text);
```

And then the addElementToModal

```
(window as any).addElementToModel = ((root: HTMLElement, standardText: {[key: string]: string}) =>
{
    init(root, standardText);
});
```

so i want to recieve it like {[key: string]: string} where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
const list = JSON.parse("@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.List)");
```

As a result you will get a plain JS array in `list` variable.

Comment: Hmm this is a part on the way i think. it makes it like this thou [{&quot;Id&quot;:&quot;

Comment: @novafluff, yes, see it, try this const list = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.List))

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = '@Model.StandardText';
```

This is just going to ToString() the object. You could use JSON.NET For example to JSON Stringify it if that's your objective. e.g.

```
var text = '@Json.SerializeObject(Model.StandardText)';
```